# The Truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm running into an issue where i cannot sort an array. I'm getting this error `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` Why exactly is this happening? I don't understand. Is it because of a tie breaker? I've been on this problem for a while and cannot figure it out.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import datasets, metrics, svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from collections import Counter
from math import sqrt

#import number data
digits = datasets.load_digits()
images_and_labels = list(zip(digits.images, digits.target))
n_samples = len(digits.images)
data = digits.images.reshape((n_samples, -1))
data_train, data_test, label_train, label_test = train_test_split(data, digits.target, test_size=0.2)

def euclidean_distance(first, second):
    distance = 0.0
    for i in range(64):
        distance += (first[i] - second[i])**2
    return np.sqrt(distance)

def get_neighbors(train_set, test_set, num_neighbors):
    distances = list()
    for test_set in train_set:
        dist = euclidean_distance(test_set, train_set)
        distances.append((train_set, dist))
    np.sort(distances)
    neighbors = list()
    for i in range(num_neighbors):
        neighbors.append(distances[i][0])
    return neighbors

results = get_neighbors(data_train, data_test, 100 )
```

Comment: Consider `a = np.array([True, False, True, False]); if a:`: what should the result of the if statement be? This is the underlying cause of the message you're seeing.

Comment: you should look at the shape of `distance`. you might have to set an axis

Comment: Since you have no if statement in your own code, it's somewhere in the underlying code that this happens. That may be because you feed it incorrect input, or because you're using outdated packages. First make sure sklearn and numpy are up to date.

Comment: full traceback, please

Answer (score 0):

At this line:

```
np.sort(distances)
```

distances is a list of tuples - each containing a pair of numpy arrays. For example:

```
>>> distances[0]
(array([[ 0.,  0.,  6., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  3., 13., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ..., 16.,  7.,  0.],
        ...,
        [ 0.,  0.,  1., ..., 16.,  5.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1., 13., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1., ..., 14.,  6.,  0.]]),
 array([54.40588203, 51.7107339 , 58.72818744, 83.80930736, 77.37570678,
        58.25804665, 54.18486874, 54.47935389, 54.40588203, 52.13444159,
        73.54590403, 87.35559513, 79.01898506, 66.55824517, 54.61684722,
        54.56189146, 54.40588203, 50.55689864, 78.65748534, 74.60562981,
        74.37741593, 72.70488292, 55.08175742, 54.41507144, 54.40588203,
        49.43682838, 76.51143705, 70.9577339 , 75.94076639, 65.90902821,
        56.90342696, 54.40588203, 54.40588203, 55.06359959, 73.06161783,
        73.71566998, 82.50454533, 70.        , 54.        , 54.40588203,
        54.40588203, 53.10367219, 75.16648189, 78.7273777 , 74.06753675,
        67.00746227, 55.6596802 , 54.40588203, 54.40588203, 52.5832673 ,
        68.82586723, 80.74651695, 74.24957912, 72.9725976 , 56.59505279,
        53.8702144 , 54.40588203, 52.06726419, 61.10646447, 83.5463943 ,
        84.92938243, 61.83041323, 53.38539126, 54.2678542 ]))
```

The error is because `np.sort` doesn't know how to deal with this.